# tinyMce shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working with an asp.net website where we have implemented shortcuts in our page master, but these don't seem to work when the tinymce editor has focus. is there any way to solve this issue? it doesn't matter if it's at master page level or tinymce-level.

I have tried to create custom methods via the addShortcut method but this causes my javascript to error.

```
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), new Guid().ToString(), "ShortCutModule();", true);

        string enableShortcuts = @"function enableShortcuts(){"+
            @"tinyMCE.get('"+"myKey2"+this.ID+@"').addShortcut(""Ctrl+Shift+f12"",""nix"",""jourcut"");";

        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), new Guid().ToString(), enableShortcuts, true);


        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        page.GetType(),
        "MyKey2" + this.ID, @"<script type=""text/javascript"" >" +
        @"tinyMCE.init({" +
        @"oninit : ""enableShortcuts"","+
        @"mode: ""exact""," +
        @"elements: """ + this.ID + @"""," +
        @"theme: ""advanced""," +
        @"plugins: ""spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview""," +
        @"theme_advanced_buttons1: ""bold,italic,underline,|,outdent,indent,|,cut,copy,paste,|,undo,redo""," +
        @"theme_advanced_toolbar_location: ""top""," +
        @"theme_advanced_toolbar_align: ""left""," +
        @"theme_advanced_statusbar_location: ""bottom""," +
        "custom_shortcuts : false," +
        "theme_advanced_path : false," +
        "setup : function(ed) {" +
            "ed.addCommand('jourcut', function() {CutFromJournal();});" +
        "}" +
        "});" +
        "</script>",
false);
```

Comment: what kind of javascript error do you get

Comment: That my object reference is null. probably because I haven't initialized it yet. but it seems like the one needs the other and the other way around

Comment: what code does "CutFromJournal()" contain?

Comment: thank you for your help :-D I figured out how to fix it :-D

Comment: in that case you should answer your own question